# Redirect to another web page in Kotlin Web Front End development

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-frontend

I am trying to redirect to another web page in Kotlin for Web Front End development. I have wrote this code to achieve this:

```
window.location.href = "adduser1.html"
```

But if I write this code then, the code written after this line are not executing. Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is normal browser behaviour, and it is not specific to Kotlin.  When you change `window.location.href`, code execution stops and the browser performs the redirect.

Comment: Then how can I redirect to another page?